# How do I assign a commit from one branch to another?

Tags: git

Our workflow is to create branches via JIRA.  I knew a branch (named A) would soon be merged w/ master and that is the work I needed to build on.  So what I did was branch off A locally, creating B.

After A was merged w/ master, I created a new branch C with the appropriate branch name.

On branch B there is a single commit, and I would like that work to be as if it were committed on branch C. How do I do this so that it looks as though I never created B off of A?

Update: No work has been done on C at this point; it has just been created.

Comment: `git cherry-pick [commit hash of commit]` on the branch you want to commit to

Comment: Do you want the history leading to that commit on branch C too, or just the single commit itself? If you want the single commit, cherry pick it (see mousetail's comment), if you want the history leading to it, merge it into C.

Comment: I want it to be as if I had created branch C and did all the work I actually did on B. So cherry-pick sounds like the right answer.

Comment: This worked; if you make answer I will accept.

Comment: Are there commits on C? If so, where on C do you want B's commit to go? It would help if you drew a diagram, perhaps.

Comment: No commits on C; the branch has just been created on Jira. The solution by mousetail worked.

Comment: The solution by knittl is better and you should accept it. Branches are just virtual name-tags; if you want the name "C" to point at this commit, just attach the name "C" to that commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options:

- Simply rename your B branch to C: `git branch -m C B`
- Or branch C off B and abandon B: `git checkout -b C B` (eventually: `git branch -d B`).
- To copy the commit (as new commit with different SHA1 hash) to branch C: `git cherry-pick B` (while on branch C)

Comment: Will this have any issues with not tracking the remote branch?

Comment: @MathStudent remote-tracking branch can be changed with `git branch --set-upstream-to=UPSTREAM`, if it needs to be changed

Comment: I'm not sure the OP has given enough info to answer the question yet.

Comment: If I try moving: "fatal: A branch named 'C' already exists."
Is it safe to just delete C locally since no work has been done?

Comment: @MathStudent yes, it is safe to delete. A branch in Git is simply a label given to a commit. If C was created from B, but no commits made, then `B^{commit}==C^{commit}`